# Side keyboard on tvOs

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I noticed the keyboard in some apple tv is not full screen. UISearchBar inline keyboard is full width on one tv but on another tv, searchbar and inline keyboard appear on the left side.
Anyone know why?
[image: left side keyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard appears on the side like this if the system detects that the Siri Remote isn't paired. For example, if you normally use a universal remote to control your Apple TV, this keyboard would be easier to use with only the arrow keys.

If you pair a Siri Remote, then the keyboard will use its normal "linear" appearance.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to force the keyboard to always be linear?